# My flow fails for no reason: Invalid Template Language? This is what I do

Tags: power-automate

Team,

Occasionally my flow fails and its enough test it manually to running again. However, I want to avoid that this error ocurrs again to stay in calm.

The error that appears is this:

`Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Periodo' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'split' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#split for usage details.'.`

And it appears in 2 of the 4 variables that I create:

`Client` and `Periodo`

[image: This is how my entire flow looks like. The two variables of the right side are the 'problem' aparrentely]

The variable `Client`looks this:

[image: Can we see how the text are, essentialy, a string.]

The same scenario to "Periodo".

[image: Well, in this attempt here appear the error.]

The variables are build in the same way:

[image: Client variable:]

His formula:

```
trim(first(split(first(skip(split(outputs('Compos'),'client = '),1)),'indicator')))
```

[image: Periodo variable:]

His formula:

```
trim(first(split(first(skip(split(outputs('Compos'),'period = '),1)),'DATA_REPORT_DELIVERY')))
```

The same scenario to the 4 variables. 4 of them strings (numbers).

Also I attached email example where I extract the info:

[image: Example:]

```
CO NIV ICE REFRESCOS DE SOYA has finished successfully.CO NIV ICE REFRESCOS DE SOYA

User
    binary.struggle@mail.com

Parameters
    output = 7
    country = 170
    period = 202204012
    DATA_REPORT_DELIVERY = NO
    read_persistance = YES
    write_persistance = YES
    client = 18277
    indicator_group = SALES
```

Could you give some help? I reach some attepmpts succeded but it fails for no apparent reason:

[image: Two of the succeded results:]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the string your running all of this over/parsing?

Comment: Hi, Skin . I hope understand you well. I shared a mail example.

Comment: Can you paste the text rather than an image? Exactly as you receive it.

Comment: I already paste the body of the mail. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're interested but I'd do it a slightly different way.  It's a little more verbose but it will work and it makes your expressions a lot simpler.

I've just taken two of your desired outputs and provided a solution for those, one being `client` and the other being `country`.  You can apply the other two as need be given it's the same pattern.

If I take `client` for example, this is the concept.

[image: Flow]

**Initialize Data**

This is your string that you provided in your question.

**Initialize Split Lines**

This will split up your string for each new line.  The expression for this step is ...

```
split(variables('Data'), '\n')
```

However, you can't just enter that expression into the editor, you need to do it and then edit in in code view and change it from `\\n` to `\n`.

[image: Code View]

**Filter For 'client'**

This will filter the array created from the split line step and find the item that contains the word `client`.

```
`contains(item(), 'client')`
```

On the other parallel branches, you'd change out the word to whatever you're searching for, e.g. `country`.

This should give us a single item array with a string.

**Initialize 'client'**

Finally, we want to extract the value on the right hand side of the equals sign.  The expression for this is ...

```
trim(split(body('Filter_For_''client''')[0], '=')[1])
```

Again, just change out the `body` name for the other action in each case.

I need to put `body('Filter_For_''client''')[0]` and specify the first item in an array because the filter step returns an array.  We're going to assume the length is always 1.

**Result**

You can see from all of that, you have the value as need be.  Like I said, it's a little more verbose but (I think) easier to follow and troubleshoot if something goes wrong.

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi! I appreciate a lot the effort you put to help me. I'm already trying to replicate the examples that you give me but I find trouble with the "Initialize Split Lines" component. I'm not able to edit the "\\n" to "\n" and I think that it causes my last extraction doesn't filter correctly. The output obtained is:

 "7
 country".

Comment: I'll add the evidence. And again, thank you for the support @Skin.

Comment: I mean, the output desired, in that case, is only the "7" but it extracts also the next line.

Comment: Hi again, @Skin. There's a way that you can share me that flow? I spent a few hours trying to understand it and I want to. But it will be easier if I can handle it.

Comment: I ended up deleting it but with the code change, did you go to `Code View` for the flow?  The image I showed is for the individual step, you can't change the code here, you can only view it, you need to click on the code view button in the toolbar at the top.